# Obtener json de una url

Tags: javascript

Quiero ver el json obtenido de una url en html dentro de una etiqueta con id codigo, pero al ser funcion asincrona lo que obtengo es un [object Promise] y en la consola obtengo el json.

```javascript
let prueba = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=41.63125237270472&lon=-4.742565007934635&format=json';

async function load() {
    let url = prueba;
    let obj = null;

    try {
        obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error');
    }

    console.log(obj);
    return obj;
}

load();
document.getElementById('codigo').innerHTML = load();;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ponlo dentro de la función así:

```js
let prueba = 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=41.63125237270472&lon=-4.742565007934635&format=json';

async function load() {
    let url = prueba;
    let obj = null;

    try {
        obj = await (await fetch(url)).json();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('error');
    }

    console.log(obj);

    jsonObj = JSON.stringify(obj);
    document.getElementById('codigo').innerHTML = jsonObj;
    
    // return obj;
}

load();
```

```html
<div id="codigo">

</div>
```